# Default core name in solr 1.4.1

Tags: solr

I cannot set up default core in solr 1.4.1

```
<cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="core0">
```

It doesn't work. The server starts as usual and works but doesn't allow making requests without core name. I went through their release notes and couldn't find when they started supporting this parameter. Does solr 1.4.1 support it? What are the other options?

UPD: The whole solr configs looks this way

```
<solr persistent="true">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="core0">
    <core name="core0" instanceDir="./core0" />
    <core name="core1" instanceDir="./core1" />
  </cores>
</solr>
```

How I check:

1) Check without core(returns HTTP 400 now, "missing solr core name in path")
http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/select?q=test&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

2) Check with core(response is correct) http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/core0/select?q=test&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No. DefaultCoreName is not supported in solr 1.4.1
I installed solr 3.5 and set up multicore environment, after specifying defaultCoreName I was able to perform the following two requests and the response was the same

http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/select/?q=solr&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

and

http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/core0/select/?q=solr&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

Answer (score 0):

Yes it supported in 1.4.

You can try by making it as persistant = true if you want to add more core by the using solr api for managing the core.

If you don't want the default core you can remove it from the xml.

You can have you solr.xml as below and try.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="true">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1">
    <core name="collection1" instanceDir="./"/>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

another would be if add your own core by mentioning the data dir and insatance dir..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="true">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="Test" instanceDir="/home/abhijit/Downloads/Solr/" dataDir="/home/abhijit/Downloads/Solr/Test/data"/>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I updated the question. My solr.xml looks exactly like you wrote, but anyway it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: As you are using core...that means you have a multi-core setup and have to include the core in the URL. e.g. instead of requesting http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*%3A* you have to request http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select/?q=*%3A*

Comment: If you browse to http://localhost:8983/solr/ you will the list of core that are there ..

Comment: From https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%20(supported%20through%204.x) defaultCoreName - The name of a core that will be used for requests that don't specify a core. If you have one core and want to use the features specified on this page, then this provides a way to keep your URLs the same.

Comment: I thought that defaultCoreName is designed for this purpose, when I want to have default core, and I don't want to specify it everytime in my request, isn't it?

Comment: otherwise, what's is the purpose of this feature? I don't see any different with it and without it

Comment: there is difference...it helps you to splits you data...consider if your two diff product info..you can create two core...and seperate the data instead of keeping in one...If you dont need any core ...then can delete the entries and continue without core...

Comment: Multiple cores let you have a single Solr instance with separate configurations and indexes, with their own config and schema for very different applications, but still have the convenience of unified administration. Individual indexes are still fairly isolated, but you can manage them as a single application, create new indexes on the fly by spinning up new SolrCores....https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin

Comment: Thank you for all your responses. I cannot move this conversation to chat(not enough reputation). I know why we use cores. I cannot understand why we have "defaultCoreName" feature. What does it change?